# Find the first appearance of a number in associative array

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

Let's say the following is true:

- I have an associative array containing an unknown number of elements.
- The keys are integers, starting at `1`, and each is one more than the last.
- There is an element with key *N* whose value is `1`.
- The value of each element with a key less than *N* is `0`.
- The value of each element with a key greater than *N* is `1`.

This is the array:

[image]

The question is :
***What is the fastest/smartest way to find the position of the first '1' in the array?***

Comment: But if i'm not wrong, a binary search requires me to know the length of the array and here I do not know it's length.

Comment: It's a question I got at a job interview.. that's what they told me.

Answer (score 0):

If you truly don't know the length of the array (a very odd situation), then probably all you can do is grow your search geometrically, *i.e.* skip 4, skip 8, skip 16, etc. until you find a 1, then cut back with a (geometric) binary search.

Comment: Well, there isn't any smarter way to do this other than a binary search by geometrically growth?

Comment: I'm still skeptical how you could not know the length of this array, but if it's truly unknown, then think of it as an infinite sequence of numbers. You may know that the sequence only increases (>=), but that doesn't help. The sequence of zeroes can be as long as the universe. You literally, theoretically, cannot optimize this in any way. Well, you can consider the maximum index (e.g. INT_MAX) of your system the bound, and binary search like that.

Comment: It's a question I got at a job interview.. that's what they told me.

Comment: If you've recalled the question correctly, then they probably wanted to see how you thought about a weird situation, wanted you to realize that there is no optimal way / INT_MAX / etc.

Comment: @NivApo So what do you looking for? A O(1) solution? how can you achieve better than O(log n) for searching?

Comment: The complexity of the suggested approach is O(log N + log N/2) = O(log N), the same as binary search. This is very very good.

Answer (score 0):

`array_search` is your best bet

```
// Make up some data...
$data = [];
for ($i = 1; $i <= 20; ++$i) {
    $data[$i] = rand(0,5);
}


var_dump($data);

// Find the first one...
echo 'The first 1 is at position: ' . array_search(1, $data);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php